# How do I completely remove my PyTorch and ONNX installations?

Tags: software-installation, anaconda

I created a new anaconda environment but I forgot to activate it before installing PyTorch with `conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch` and onnx with `pip install ./onnx`

How do I safely delete these installations ?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall onnx
conda uninstall pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu pytorch
```